# How do you build a link with a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

For the sake of simplicity let's say I have a 3 field HTML form, and after the user completes the form and submits, it builds a special link and sends the browser to it.

```
Field A (Text-input) = 1
Field B (Drop-down) = 2
Field C (Text-input) = Apples
```

User submits, takes user to:

```
myurl.com/?a=1&b=2&c='apples'
```

Comment: Is C supposed to be "text" input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action` and `method` properties in form.

```
<form action="YOUR_URL" method="get">
<input type="text" id="a" name="a" />
<select id="b" name="b"><option value="2">2</option></select>
<input type="text" id="c" name="c" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use HTML Form [Get Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_GET_method), because:

> if a form is sent using this method the data sent to the server is
>   appended to the URL

```
<form method="get" action="myurl.com">
     <intput type="text" name="a"/>
     <input type="text" name="b" />
     <input type="text" name="c" />
     <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

More about the method attribute [you can find here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method), most important is:

> 1. post: Corresponds to the HTTP POST method ; form data are included in
>      the body of the form and sent to the server. get: Corresponds to the
> 2. HTTP GET method; form data are appended to the action attribute URL
>      with a '?' as separator, and the resulting URL is sent to the server.
>      Use this method when the form has no side-effects and contains only
>      ASCII characters.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Why does this solve the problem?