# How do I build a simple HTML form to construct a link from two form fields?

Tags: html, forms

At work, one of the systems I use outputs voyage schedules. The URL for each voyage is constructed as the form address followed by `?voyageCode=` followed by the voyage number, which is a two-letter route prefix and a three-digit voyage number.

Rather than use the standard form, which has a whole bunch of fields I never need to use, I want to build a simple page where I can just select the route and enter a voyage number.

In practical terms, I'm trying to build a form with the following:

1. A drop-down menu or set of radio buttons to select the two-letter route code;
2. A text field to enter the three-digit route code;
3. A button or link to combine those inputs into a link in the format `[LINK]?voyageCode=[ROUTE CODE][VOYAGE NUMBER]`

My HTML knowledge is pretty outdated, and I've never worked much with forms. Can anyone advise on how I can construct this?

Comment: The closest answer I've been able to find so far is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504654/how-do-you-build-a-link-with-a-form, which doesn't give much information on how to construct the link itself.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a `select` tag for the dropdown and a classic `input text` for the route coude ?

Then for the link part, you should capture the `click` event on your button through `onClick` and then call a small function that'll basically do that :

```
function concatRouteCode(){
    var select= document.getElementById("routeCodeLetters");
    var routeCodeLetters = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    var routeCodeNumber = document.getElementById('routeCode').value;

    return routeCodeLettres+routeCodeNumber;
}
```

Comment: So it's something that would need javascript to work, rather than something I can do in basic HTML? Haven't done any scripting since the late 90s, and wasn't very good at it then... :-(

Comment: You want to process data from your form, HTML won't do anything about it so as far as i know, you either need to use JavaScript or a backend solution. JS still the most lightweight and appropriate imo.

Comment: As for the form itself, I'm currently using `select ... option` for the route code and `input ... text` for the voyage number, just as you suggest.

Comment: Right. Well, I'll have a bit of a google and see if I can find some code that'll do the job. Cheers. :-)

Comment: The one i gave you should do the trick. What do you want when the button is clicked ? Display the link in your document or redirect immediately the user ?

Comment: Ideally just go straight to that URL. As for the code you suggest, I need to figure out how to use it - as I say, javascript isn't something I've used much, so I have little to no idea how to make it go...

Comment: Like @radulfr suggested in his response, this line will do the work:
    `location.href = "base URL here" + "?voyageCode=" + routeCodeLetters + routeCodeNumber;`

The `return` statement isn't needed anymore in the function since the only action you'll do is redirect the user, other process are pointless.

MDN ref for location : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location

Comment: Right. I'll give it a go and see if I can figure out how to build that into the bits I do know. :-)

Comment: Mozilla web docs is really a great place to gather information about what you'd like to do. Don't hesitate if you have any other question. And if i answered to this one, don't forget to close this topic by chosing one of the proposition we gave (if it does answer).

Comment: Yeah, I'll see if I can figure out how to implement the suggestions first. I'm sure they're good solutions, I just need to teach myself the framework to make use of them. :-)

Comment: I have to admit defeat, I'm afraid. Just too many things on my mind and too much stuff going on at work, making it hard to focus and wrap my mind around this. I'm used to finding things I don't know, but it's a disconcerting feeling to find that I have difficulty learning them. Huge thanks for your input - I'll come back to it when I can think straight.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to combine the codes into a single query parameter, you'll have to use Javascript to fetch the values of the two fields and change the location. You don't need Javascript if you put the values into separate parameters, as in `?routeCode=xx&voyageNumber=123`. In that case you would just give the select element the attribute `name=routeCode` and the input field the attribute `name=voyageNumber`.

In case you want to go with the first approach, you'd have something like

```
document.getElementById("idOfSubmitButton").addEventListener("load", function() {
    const routeCode = document.getElementById("idOfSelectElement").value;
    const voyageNumber = document.getElementById("idOfInputField").value;
    location.href = "base URL here" + "?voyageCode=" + routeCode + voyageNumber;
});
```

Comment: Cheers - I'm looking up Javascript syntax to figure out which of the two suggestions best fits my needs. Hardly ever used Javascript before, so it's a bit beyond me at the moment. :-)

Comment: I have to admit defeat, I'm afraid. Just too many things on my mind and too much stuff going on at work, making it hard to focus and wrap my mind around this. I'm used to finding things I don't know, but it's a disconcerting feeling to find that I have difficulty learning them. Huge thanks for your input - I'll come back to it when I can think straight.